# How to correctly shade transmissive gumdrops?

Tags: shaders

I want to preface this by saying that despite the blown-out appearance, it's definitely not a lighting problem. It's a shader thing; here's the blend file: [Click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jeAxz3ECSESq30-CQxe7sJiYgbR369JK/view?usp=sharing)

Here's a pic of a recent render. [image]As you can see, the light on these gum drops are not really reflecting even though the light source is facing towards them.
Curiously, I can see that the light is obviously passing through when see render from back (camera facing the light source) :[image] another odd thing is that the shaders on the sugar crystals are multicolored while the gums are all a similar green color.

This is an animated scene where the gumdrops move.
Not sure if this is relevant info, but, the sugar crystals were made with geometry nodes. I want the gumdrops to be multicolored and not the crystals.

Any advice on setting up the nodes correctly for these?

Image of gumdrop node setup here:
[image]
sugar crystal shader nodes here:

[image]

Comment: Please can you explain what you’re trying to do with the Fresnel mixing between Refraction and Glossy? That would seem to be part of the problem as there isn’t any ‘diffuse’ surface response. The Multiply by 0.5 will further reduce the surface response by pushing it more towards the Refraction. Is there a reason you aren’t using Principled shader for the jelly?

Comment: One other thing... the 'Random Per Island' is going to always come out as zero for the Volume - it's a UV thing, rather than a volume thing - and so they are always going to be tinted green. Use the Object Info 'Random' instead (the node is on your screenshot so I presume you've maybe already gone down that route).

Comment: @RichSedman Yeah for your second question about the "random per island. The problem when I use object info random is that the gumdrop colors is not varied at all. (including the crystals). When I do that, the entire gumdrop including crystals is green. As for the first question. There is no particular reason I did that, I was following a tutorial on making a singular red gumdrop. there was not really an explanation to the placement of the nodes. It was just a screenshot of how to achieve the same results, which in this case was to create a singular red drop.

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? If I use Geometry Nodes in 2.93Alpha and use Point Instance to create "sugar" on the surface, the crystals retain the material from the source object and ObjectInfo.Random is populated with a unique value per crystal. Using 'Random Per Island' leaves it stuck at zero - so this seems different to the behavour you're seeing. Can you get the latest version and retry?